# Adding a new table to Xml Dataset by the click of a button in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find out how and if it is possible to add a new table to a dataset by letting the end user select the name and create a new table and submit it. When the user clicks submit I am planning on it adding the name to a combo box on another form and when they select it, it will show the content of that table. If anyone could give me advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim dataset as New DataSet
Dim table as New DataTable("tablename")
'add structure of datatable
Dim col As DataColumn
col = New DataColumn
col.ColumnName = "col1"
col.DataType = GetType(String)
table.Columns.Add(col)
col = New DataColumn
col.ColumnName = "col2"
col.DataType = GetType(String)
table.Columns.Add(col)

'add to dataset
dataset.Tables.Add(table)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: When I tried this it makes sense to me but when I try that (& and I made a slight edit so that it will make the table in an already made dataset) it just doesn't add it

Comment: Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim table As New DataTable("tablename")
        'add structure of datatable
        Dim col As DataColumn
        col = New DataColumn
        col.ColumnName = "col1"
        col.DataType = GetType(String)
        table.Columns.Add(col)
        col = New DataColumn
        col.ColumnName = "col2"
        col.DataType = GetType(String)
        table.Columns.Add(col)

        'add to dataset
        DataSet1.Tables.Add(table)

    End Sub
End Class

Comment: What I am confused with now is I am seeing that it is working because if I press the button it shows an error message saying there is a table with this name already. So i know that it is working but then it is not being shown in the dataset once the application is already closed

Comment: Do you mean you want the data to be saved to a some form of database when the application is close?

Comment: Yes is a dataset a form of a database? Sorry if that is incorrect I am new to programming.